# Help with CSS seclectors for usage with selenium

Tags: css, selenium

```
<div id="footerSearchInputDefault" class="defaultText" style="visibility: hidden;">Search myTwonky</div>
```

With respect to selenium, in the above, what is

1. attribute
2. element
3. value
4. text
5. label

I keep getting confused between these terms and the explaination of the above example would help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Element**: `<div></div>`. This is the basic block, everything else is added to the element.
2. **Attribute**: `id, class, style`. Attributes are any extra information added inside the element's tag.
3. **Value**: None in your example. Value is a special **attribute** that form elements have. A browser usually uses the value attribute to transmit data when the form is submitted (think of a username-password form)
4. **Text**: `Search myTwonky`. This is anything wrapped by the element tags.
5. **Label**: None in your example. A label is a special **element** that usually goes before an input element (again in a form). This is usually something like "Password:" which as the name suggests, is a label for an input field in a form